# Jest mocking a functional component

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I feel like I'm missing something. I'm trying to mock a functional component and it keeps giving me an error

If I do

```
TestRenderer.create(
      <FunctionalComponent/>
)
```

It gives the error

```
Invariant Violation: FunctionalComponent(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

If I change it to a class based component it works.

How can I mock a functional component? thanks!

edit:

I tried mocking this component

```
const SampleComponent = () => {
  return <View/>
}
```

And it gives the the error,

But this one

```
class SampleClassComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <View/>
  }
}
```

Does not

error happens when running

```
jests.mock('path/to/component')
```

Comment: Can you post your test component?

Comment: @Fricken Hamster Where did you find the example for the additional code you added?

Comment: @Fricken Hamster Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return something in your functional component, even if it is null.  The functional component is Link.

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

function Link(props) {
  return null;
}

const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
  <Link/>
);

console.log(testRenderer.toJSON());

export default Link;
```

or

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

function Link(props) {
  return <a href={props.page}>{props.children}</a>;
}

const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
  <Link/>
);

console.log(testRenderer.toJSON());

export default Link;
```

References:

- Facebook, Inc. "Test Renderer". React. https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html (accessed October 8, 2019).

Comment: Hmm, I am definitely returning something in my functional component, the actual app is working.

Comment: @Fricken Hamster Add the functional component code (or similar code if you're not okay with others seeing the original) to your question, by editing it.  I can't think of another reason off the top of my head, and would just be shooting in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added components that I tested right now that gave the errors.